# Python ZipFIle Including Empty Zip File With Same Name

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am attempting to zip a directory with several files and ZipFile is including an empty zip file with the same zip file name with the zipped files

My requirement is to only include the 2 .csv files and not add an empty .zip file with the same name.

Thanks for any advice.

Example:
'E:/GL/download_ceridian':
file1.csv
file2.csv

Code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED
import pathlib

zip_path = 'E:/GL/download_ceridian/ceridian.zip'
directory_to_zip =  'E:/GL/download_ceridian'

folder = pathlib.Path(directory_to_zip)

with ZipFile(zip_path, 'w' , ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
    for file in folder.iterdir():
        zip.write(file , arcname=file.name)
```

Results:

E:/GL/download_ceridian
ceridian.zip:
file1.csv
file2.csv
ceridian.zip (empty)

Comment: simply use `if/else` to check file extension and compress only files with extension `.csv`, or to skip files with extension `.zip`. You can also check full name and skip file with the same name. You may also check file size and skip empty files. All this need to use `if/else`

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create the file list before opening the zip-file for writing:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED
import pathlib

zip_path = 'E:/GL/download_ceridian/ceridian.zip'
directory_to_zip =  'E:/GL/download_ceridian'

folder = pathlib.Path(directory_to_zip)
filelist = list(folder.iterdir())

with ZipFile(zip_path, 'w' , ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
    for file in filelist:
        zip.write(file , arcname=file.name)
```

Alternatively, you could check whether a file meets your criteria to be added to the zip inside the loop:

```
with ZipFile(zip_path, 'w' , ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
    for file in folder.iterdir():
        if file.name.endswith(".csv"):
            zip.write(file , arcname=file.name)
```

Comment: This was super helpful...really appreciate the prompt response!

Comment: I think this last remaining hurdle I am facing here is that I am still creating an empty .zip file when no files exist in the directory.  I have been reviewing the logic and other examples and can't seem to find a clean way to only create a .zip when files exist.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Add `if filelist:` before creating the zipfile?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `if/else` to check file extension (`file.suffix`) and compress only files with extension `.csv` (and `.CSV`, `.CsV`, `.cSv`, etc. - so it may need `.lower()`),

```
for file in folder.iterdir():
    if file.suffix.lower() == ".csv":
        zip.write(file, arcname=file.name)
```

Or to skip files with extension `.zip` (and `.ZIP`, `.ZiP`, `.zIp`, etc.).

```
for file in folder.iterdir():
    if file.suffix.lower() != ".zip":
        zip.write(file, arcname=file.name)
```

You can also check full name and skip file with the same name.

```
for file in folder.iterdir():
    if file.name != "ceridian.zip":
        zip.write(file, arcname=file.name)
```

You may also check file size and skip empty files.

```
for file in folder.iterdir():
    if file.stat().st_size != 0:
        zip.write(file, arcname=file.name)
```

All this need to use `if/else`

You may also use it with `and`, `or` to create more complex filter - like

```
if file.suffix.lower() != '.zip' and file.stat().st_size != 0:
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need only files with extension `.csv` then you can use `.glob('*.csv')` instead of `.iterdir()` - and it doesn't need `if/else`

```
for file in folder.glob('*.csv'):
    zip.write(file , arcname=file.name)
```

Comment: while your first suggestion does indeed provide a workaround, it would be better to address the underlying issue more directly, which is that `Path.iterdir` is generating the contents of the folder after the zip file is created. Your second suggestion does that by replacing `iterdir` with `glob` and I think that or moving the call to `iterdir` as suggested in another solution are preferable

Comment: @avigil I tried to show that problem can be resolve using different `if/else`. Idea with `glob()` came to me later.